# Ways to use server date in an AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, server

Is there a "nice" way to set the server's date to an angularJS app?

Let's say that I have an API route to get this, sort of /api/date and I can call it with an angular service called dateService:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('DateService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/date', { }, {
    });

}]);
```

I need to get the date as soon as the app starts because my html file uses a function based on that date to display something. Otherwise I'll get an "undefined" error everytime I call it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could serve the date in a dynamically generated page such as PHP which then defines it as a javascript variable before the rest of your angular code is interpreted and loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in app.run

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state, DateService) {

            // call date service and save it in $rootScope

        });
```

Comment: It would be nice if people can comment and explain before marking answer as not useful.

Comment: Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system configuration during application run time.

Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application. It is executed after all of the service have been configured and the injector has been created.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have the back-end server return a timestamp in UTC.
2. Parse the timestamp value with `var date = new Date(serverTimestampValue);`
3. You now have a JS Date object that can be used with Angular Date filters.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that my function is called before the http call is resolved, so I'm getting a console error when I load the page for the first time.

Comment: He means forgoing the service and api altogether and have your web server put it into yout html directly (e.g. php echo). This is the same approach as the comment by Rob on your post.

Comment: Add the value in your HTML file server-side, give it a DOM ID, and access it before our function runs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ui-router` for routing and if you need to learn the timestamp before showing anything to user you can use the `resolve` property of ui-router. Basically it resolves what you need before activating a state, and if you retrieve your server time in your parent state you can be sure that you will have the timestamp before anything starts in your application. Here is an example how to do it:

```
angular.module("yourApp").config(["$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state("topState", {
                abstract: true,
                template: "<ui-view></ui-view>",
                controller: ["$rootScope", "serverTimestamp", function ($rootScope, serverTimestamp) {
                    $rootScope.serverTime = new Date(serverTimestamp);
                    //Do what you need to do with the server time, from now on you will have access to server time from each controller in your app.
                }],
                resolve: {
                    serverTimestamp: ["", function (bakkalBrandService) {
                        return yourService.retrieveTimestampFromServer();
                    }]
                }
            })
    }])
```

Comment: Nice answer! Is it possible using ngRoute?

Comment: @lerp90 did you look at my answer about getting the date in app.run ? all the code that's needed to kickstart the application can go in app.run

Comment: @lerp90 Seems like you can do it, just check the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735221/using-the-ngroute-resolve-parameter-with-an-injected-promise

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the execution of angular app by manually bootstrapping it rather than auto initialization.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap
This way you can do the following to get the server settings and have it available when your angular app starts.

```
//Define a global settings object. add proper namespace as per your app.
var myServerConfig = (function () {
    var settings = {
        someDefaultSetting: 'someDefaultValue'
    };
    return {
        init: function (serverSettings) {
            settings = $.extend(settings, serverSettings);
        },
        settings: settings
    }
})();

//Define angular wrapper for your global object
var serverSettings = angular.module('server.settings', []);

serverSettings.factory('serverSettings', ['$window', function () {
    return $window.myServerConfig.settings;
}]);

//On dom ready get all settings and bootstrap angular app
$(document).ready(function () {
    //You will have to show some animation if you are making ajax call
    //also if errors out handle that scenario
    //Other option is to render settings from server on page load as mentioned in other answers
   $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/api/settings',
            error: function (error) {
               //show user message that app cannot be loaded
            },
            success: function (setting) {
                  myServerConfig.init(setting);
                  bootStrapMyApp();
            }
        });

function bootStrapMyApp() {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myApp').service('DateService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

  this.date = null;
  var self = this;

  $resource('/api/date', { }, {
  }).then(function(data){
      self.date = data.date;
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assign it to a service variable after you get it.

```
angular.module('myApp').service('DateService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    this.date = null;
    var self = this;

    $resource('/api/date', { }, {
    }).then(function(data){
        self.date = data.date;
    });
}]);
```

Then call the service to get it when you need it.

```
$scope.date = function() {
    return DateService.date;
}
```

Comment: `self.date = data.date? new Date(data.date) : null;`

Comment: he is asking to get the date as soon as the app starts. how is this an answer?